# Open new frame or chart when a bar or a bar chart is clicked

Tags: java, swing, charts, jfreechart

I have a bar chart which gets the dataset from the mysql database, and I am stuck on using the `chartMouseClicked`. Currently the code prints when clicked on x or y axis bars, as I learned in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28899094/230513), but how do I set that when I click a particular bar on x or y axis and open a new frame or chart. Also an information box would be fine.

```
private void lineChart() {
// *************** ADDING BAR CHART FROM DATABASE *****************************

try {
    String sql = "select Region, Male, Female from ObeseLondon limit 14";
    JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(MySQL.Connectdb(), sql);
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("", "Town", "No. Of Obese People", dataset, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, true);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    BarRenderer render = null;
    //CategoryPlot plot = null;
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, Color.green);
    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.yellow);
    render = new BarRenderer();

    org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame chartframe = new org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame("Query Chart", chart);
    //chartframe.setVisible(true);
    //chartframe.setSize(200,500);
    panelBarChart.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    panelBarChart.add(chartPanel);
    panelBarChart.validate();
    chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

@Override
public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {
    ChartEntity entity = event.getEntity();
    System.out.println(entity);
}

@Override
public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent event) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a `JOptionPane` in your handler, as shown below in a `ChartMouseListener` added to [`BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java). The pane displays a panel of labels, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513), but a nested `ChartPanel` would work as well.

[image]

```
@Override
public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {
    CategoryItemEntity entity = (CategoryItemEntity) event.getEntity();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    Comparable row = entity.getRowKey();
    Comparable col = entity.getColumnKey();
    panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(row)));
    panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(col)));
    panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(entity.getDataset().getValue(row, col))));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, panel);
}
```