# How to show current price on y-axis with jfreechart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm trying to indicate the current price on the y-axis of a line chart. How do I place the label on the axis outside the plot?

I have tried the value marker but it doesn't extend outside the chart.

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: The expected output]

this is what I have right now

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb09y.png)

Comment: Can you add a `ChartMouseListener` and update an adjacent component, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28926590/230513)?

Comment: @trashgod this should be done on price change not on mouse click

Comment: Handle updates in `chartMouseMoved()`.

Comment: @trashgod thanks for the quick reply. How do I align the coordinates of the adjacent component with the chart.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't; you'll have to recapitulate the details in the adjacent component.

Comment: @trashgod can i overlay a Jlabel on the chartpanel?

Comment: I never tried. Why not a tooltip, annotation or title?